# Mesh Analysis for Complicated Circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis, mesh-analysis

**How do I solve this Circuit with Mesh Analysis method?** Help Please. Specificly with mesh analysis please, with nodal analysis its easy.[image]

Comment: Show your working and where you go stuck.

Comment: The thing is that I dont know how to solve it. at all. I have 1 super - mesh (because of the current source in the middle), and another "super-mesh" because of the dependent current source on the right. The dependent current source makes it complicated for me, and I dont know how to make the equaitions for the circuit now.

Comment: @JhonMargalit As user287001 asks, is there a requirement for a super-mesh that you haven't disclosed? You don't need one to solve this problem. So it's important to know exactly what you are asking. Also, you should draw your circuit into your question using the schematic editor. I find I cannot even be sure of values I think I may be reading. Your writing isn't clear to me on a couple of details and you haven't labeled the devices, either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you see a current loop which goes through your both current sources and the 4kOhm resistor. You got stuck because you couldn't figure out how to write KVL equation for that loop.

But that loop doesn't need an equation, it has current 0.001Vx/8

You need 2 KVL equations which contain unknown loop currents of the voltage sources.

The third equation is got by setting the sum of loop current from voltage source Vx/2 and loop current 0.001Vx/8 equal with minus 1uA. This trick (=to present a current source as a sum of 2 loop currents) is also used in many supermesh examples although this isn't one of them.

Comment: Then by that I'm not doing a super-mesh. Am I right or I got you wrong?

Comment: I didn't suggest supermesh. If the mesh current loop method rules in your school demand it  my answer is useless.